# Is there any bluetooth 4.0 api for Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I found that that is only http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/
Is there any other api that you have discovered?

Answer (score 2):

Motorola has one for their Droid Razr [(http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/ANN-quot-Motorola-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-API-quot-article-in/td-p/20379)](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/ANN-quot-Motorola-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-API-quot-article-in/td-p/20379).